# How am I getting the scope wrong? Unable to access this function from jQuery ".on"

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

Morning all,

I'm using the following code to somewhat imitate setInterval with AJAX:

```
//  Poll for ALERTs
(function pollForAlerts() {
    var params = { "send": 1, "poll": 1 };

    //  Set up the correct patch for sending AJAX data
    ALERTS = {};
    ALERTS.Auth = { site: data_site, uuid: data_uuid };

    ALERTS.API = function(app,data) {
         var url = "//myurl.com/alerts/"+ app +"/?";
         var data = $.extend({}, ALERTS.Auth, data);
         return url + jQuery.param(data || "") + '&timestamp='+$.now();
    }

    //  Run the AJAX request
    $.getJSON( ALERTS.API( 'touchscreen', params ) , function (response) {
        if( typeof response === "object" ) {
            for( var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ )
                renderAlert(response[i]);
        } else { setTimeout( pollForAlerts, 3000 ); }
    });
}());
```

The function runs repeatedly until it finds a response.

I'd like to then set a jQuery ".on" to restart this loop if a certain element is clicked on:

```
//  Respond to ALERT
$('#alerts').on('click', 'td.initials span', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("active abs cri");
    pollForAlerts();
});
```

However, when I do that, I get the following error in Firebug:

```
ReferenceError: pollForAlerts is not defined
http://myurl.com/alerts/static/js/touchscreen.js
Line 14
```

I can't work out why `pollForAlerts()` can't be accessed. Is it because of the self-executing function, or is it just because it's being used within jQuery's `on` function?

I'm not JavaScript expert, especially when it comes to self-executing functions and closures, so please be gentle with me!

Duncan

Comment: `Is it because of the self-executing function` Bingo!

Comment: Out of interest what is the back-end? The reason I ask is that instead of polling, you could receive the messages on the client via signal-r: http://signalr.net/. Just a thought, polling is  a bit old skool these days.

Comment: It's PHP. Is there an equivalent to signalr?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote self invoking function, These functions are executing only once in lifetime. If you want to call a function multiple times then you can write it as normal function.

Comment: So... is there no actual reason to use a self-executing function in this instance?